# module tensorflow has no attribute contrib

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I've made a piece of code using a tutorial based on tensorflow 1.6 which uses 'contrib' and this is not compatible with my current tensorflow verison (2.1.0).

I haven't been able to run the upgrade script and downgrading my version of tf causes another host of problems.

I've also tried using other modules in tensor flow 2 such as tensorflow-addons and disabling version 2 behaviour.

What to do??

Comment: You might post the exact errors you are getting from the downgrade

Comment: `tf.contrib` is not available in TensorFlow 2.x anymore. See [this RFC](https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180907-contrib-sunset.md) and [this document](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FLFJLzg7WNP6JHODX5q8BDgptKafq_slHpnHVbJIteQ/edit#gid=0) for information about how you may port `tf.contrib` code to TensorFlow 2.x.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @jdehesa

Here is the information on TensorFlow official website.

> Warning: The tf.contrib module is not included in TensorFlow 2. Many 
>   of its submodules have been integrated into TensorFlow core, or
>   spun-off into other projects like tensorflow_io, or tensorflow_addons.
>   For instructions on how to upgrade see the Migration guide.

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/contrib

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate

Or, you can just convert the code to an appropriate version for TF 2.x.

Comment: `tf.disable_v2_behavior()` does not make `tf.contrib` available in TensorFlow 2.x.